# Android camera rotation for portrait mode pictures

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to make a custom camera app. I'm taking pictures from the front facing camera without preview, but the resulting images are rotated according to the front camera orientation.

I searched through a lot of post here at stack, also the one described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29) in the android docs.

This is the solution that I came up with:

```
    private void prepareCamera(Activity a){
    //Rotation
    Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    Camera.getCameraInfo(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT,info);

    int rotation = a.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;

    Log.d("TEST","rotation: "+rotation);

    switch(rotation){
        case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break; //Natural orientation
        case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break; //Landscape left
        case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break; //Upside down
        case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break; //Landscape right
    }

    Log.d("TEST","degrees: "+degrees);

    int result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
    Log.d("TEST","result: "+result);
    result = (360 - result) % 360; //Compensate the mirror

    Log.d("TEST","result: "+result);

    //camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);

    //Parameters
    Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
    params.setRotation(result);
    params.setJpegQuality(100);

    camera.setParameters(params);

    //Preview
    SurfaceView view = new SurfaceView(context);

    try{
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(view.getHolder());
    }catch(IOException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    camera.startPreview();
}
```

It works, but I have two problems

1) I have the line, wich I took from the android docs, that "compensates the mirror". If I don't delete that line the pictures are well rotated according to the camera orientation, but they are overpassed by 180º. If I delete it the pictures are fine. I want to understand the why, if someone can please explain me.

I think its because that example code that I took from the docs its made for the SurfaceView, and it calls setDisplayOrientation(result);, when I'm using the results in .setRotation(result);. Maybe it has something to do with it?

2) When I'm testing I can rotate my phone to all directions but Upside down and get the pictures well rotated. But when I put the phone upside down, they are rotate 90, but upside down. As they were processed like Natural orientation. Maybe android wont track upside down rotation? If so, why would they with a case in the example provided by them.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [setRotation() sample](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation%28int%29):

```
public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
     if (orientation == ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) return;
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
            new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
     orientation = (orientation + 45) / 90 * 90;
     int rotation = 0;
     if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         rotation = (info.orientation - orientation + 360) % 360;
     } else {  // back-facing camera
         rotation = (info.orientation + orientation) % 360;
     }
     mParameters.setRotation(rotation);
}
```

[Display.getRotation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation%28%29), unlike orientation sensor, is limited to orientations that your current Activity supports. On some devices, the portrait upside-down orientation is not supported by system.

Comment: Thank you, now I get it. And about my first question? do you have any idea of what could be happening?